# Opposite of __conversion in Swift to assign to a value of a different type

Tags: swift

Swift provides a special method called `__conversion` that allows you to implicitly convert your type to another type. I would like to be able to define a method that allows you to go the other way: to be able to assign a custom type to another type and have it implicitly converted to allow the assignment to work.

**Forward usage that is valid:**

```
class MyClass<T> {
    var myValue : T
    func __conversion() -> T? {
        return myValue
    }
    init(value: T) {
        self.myValue = value
    }
}
func takesString(aString: String?) {
}
var myInstance = MyClass(value: "Hello")
takesString(myInstance)
```

**What I would like to do:**

```
class MyClass<T> {
    func __conversion(aValue: T) -> MyClass<T> {
        return MyClass(value: T)
    }
}

var myInstance : MyClass<String> = "Hello World" // compiler error
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that __conversion is a private method and [will be removed by the end of the beta](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1011396#1011396) so this will definitely not be possible once Swift is released.

Comment: oh noes! does that mean all the implicit conversions in the standard library will be gone too?

Comment: I can't say for sure, but I imagine they will simply make that functionality private. However, I don't think there are really to many implicit conversions in the standard library.

Comment: As of iOS 8 beta 5 they are gone: `'__conversion' functions are no longer allowed.`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding an extension to String?

```
extension String {
    func __conversion() -> MyClass {
        var myInstance = MyClass()
        myInstance.myString = self
        return myInstance
    }
}
```

It worked in an iOS playground in Xcode 6 Beta 4.

```
let anInstance: MyClass = "test"
```

---

To deal with generics:

```
class MyClass<T> {
    var myString = ""
    var myT : T?
}

extension String {
    func __conversion<T>() -> MyClass<T> {
        var myInstance = MyClass<T>()
        myInstance.myString = self
        return myInstance
    }
}

let anInstance: MyClass<Int> = "test"
```

---

BTW: I think the Apple approved answer is an init method.

```
let anInstance = MyClass(myString: "test")
```

Comment: Yes I actually did try this. But, I actually simplified my real problem for clarity. I am trying to do this with MyClass being a generic type so I can't extend the generic type like I can with a specific type.

Comment: Ya, I was hoping to not require the user explicitly construct a MyClass to do the assignment. Basically I want my type to work transparently as the other type similar to the way Optionals work.

Comment: @drewag I'm not sure it's what your looking for, but generics can work.

Comment: Ya, but I would have to create an extension for every possible type. Also, it turns out that __convertion is a private method and will be removed before the end of the beta so the whole thing is a moot point

Comment: The `__conversion<T>() -> MyClass<T>` method is generic for all `MyClass<T>` types. It's at instantiation when the specific type gets bound.

Comment: Yes, but that only works for assigning to strings. I want to be able to assign to any type and have it implicitly be converted. I want to set `myT` in your example, not `myString`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be allowed anymore using Xcode 6.0.1