# @conversion attribute in Swift 2.0

Tags: swift, swift2

I've found this [code on github](https://gist.github.com/akisute/3045876b8efffdbacdb9), custom type conversions using `@conversion` attribute.

```
class GrayShark {
    var name:String
    var howSwim:String

    init(name:String, howSwim:String) {
        self.name = name
        self.howSwim = howSwim;
    }
}

func letSharkSwim(shark:GrayShark) -> String {
    return "\(shark.name) swims like '\(shark.howSwim)'."
}

extension NilType {
    @conversion func __conversion() -> (GrayShark) {
        return GrayShark(name:"Gray Shark", howSwim:"UNBELIEVABLE POWERRRRRRRR")
    }
}
```

I tried to make extension to UInt which returns its radix 8 String representation in Swift 2.0, but I got error saying `error: unknown attribute 'conversion'
@conversion func __conversion() -> String`

So, are there any new ways to create custom conversion functions in Swift 2.0?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/24945349/1187415 (with a link to the developer forum). `__conversion` was never intended to be a public method, and was removed a long time ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't use the `@conversion` keyword in Swift 2 either (it was an undocumented API anyway, so it *may* have been removed without warning).

But you don't need anything fancy to make your `UInt` extension with Swift 2 anyway:

```
extension UInt {
    var radix8Representation: String {
        return String(self, radix: 8)
    }
}

let x = UInt(16)
print(x.radix8Representation)  // "20"
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, I know about String(_:radix:) initializer (I used it just as a test for conversion keyword), but I wanted to wrap this using conversion to something like `let r8 = 1234 as String` or `test(n: 1234)`, where `n` is `String`.

Comment: I understand now what you want precisely, thanks, it wasn't clear when I first made my answer, sorry for that. But as I say in my edited answer I can't find the `@conversion` private API anymore... it's probably been removed or renamed, I can't find any non-obsolete info about it.

Comment: It looks like this implicit conversion capability has been removed in Xcode 6 beta 6 (see [this](https://github.com/ksm/SwiftInFlux#other-changes-in-xcode-60-beta-6) but I can't find official sources). The code snippet you found must be older than Swift 1.2 and is now obsolete.