# Does Swift3 still support __conversion?

Tags: swift, implicit-conversion

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24645798/does-swift-support-implicit-conversion) I tried in playground of Swift

```
extension Double {
  func __conversion() -> UInt8 { return UInt8(self) }
  func __conversion() -> Int { return Int(self) }
  // add more if you need to
}

var d = 1.0
var u8 : UInt8 = d
```

But that just produces a stack trace:

> Playground execution failed: error: MyPlayground.playground:8:18: error: cannot convert value of type 'Double' to specified type 'UInt8'
>   var u8 : UInt8 = d
>                   ^
>                   UInt8( )
>
> - thread #1: tid = 0xa5e495, 0x000000010f86e360 com.apple.dt.Xcode.PlaygroundStub-macosx`executePlayground, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread`, stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
> - frame #0: 0x000000010f86e360 com.apple.dt.Xcode.PlaygroundStub-macosx'executePlayground
>
> ...
>
> frame #51: 0x00007fffbce3a6b9 ViewBridge`-[NSXPCSharedListener resume] + 16
>
> frame #52: 0x00007fffbce152c9 ViewBridge`NSViewServiceApplicationMain + 3022
>
> frame #53: 0x000000010f86e3a2 com.apple.dt.Xcode.PlaygroundStub-macosx`main + 34
>
> frame #54: 0x00007fffbecf8255 libdyld.dylib`start + 1

Is this a bug? Is support for `__conversion` silently terminated (I read something similar about Swift1)?

Comment: It's been removed some time ago. http://stackoverflow.com/a/24945349/2227743

Comment: Also the thread that you referenced  states that *"Swift doesn't support implicitly cast anymore in Xcode6 GM"* ...

Comment: The ability to read is definitely an advantage ;- I misinterpreted that sentence. Thanks!