# Is there a way to add functionality to the `as` keyword (type cast operator)?

Tags: swift

Suppose I wanted to be able to check if a `String` or `Any` is a valid `Date`:

```
extension Dictionary {
    mutating func prepareCustomEncoding() {
        for(key, value) in self {
            if let dte = value as? Date {
                self[key] = MyTimestamp(date: dte) as? Value
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will always fail, since you can't typecast either of those to Date. Is there a way to extend the functionality of `as`?

NOTE: I know that I could do the check for this specific example by writing constructors for `Date` using `String` and `Any`. I'm interested in the functionality of the `as` keyword.

Comment: as / as? are built-in keywords/operators, and you cannot change their behavior.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/24945349: Custom conversions were available in early beta releases of Swift, but removed in Swift 1.0.